# Swift Parse Segueing To Another View Controller When MapView Annotation Is Clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, mkmapview

I currently have a UIMapView with different annotations pinned for the different locations of users on the map. I'm trying to segue to the respective users profile when the annotation is clicked. Here's my code to set up the annotations:

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "location")

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in


        if let brandsLocation = objects {

            for object in brandsLocation {

                if let brandLocation = object as? PFObject {

                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                    let annotationPoint = object["geoPoint"] as! PFGeoPoint

                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationPoint.latitude, annotationPoint.longitude)

                    annotation.title = brandLocation["annotationTitle"] as? String

                    annotation.subtitle = brandLocation["annotationSubtitle"] as? String

                    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)




                }

            }

        }
    }
```

This is where I believe the segue is supposed to happen, however it isn't doing anything for some reason.

```
       // When user taps on the disclosure button you can perform a segue 
       to navigate to another view controller
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, 
 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView{

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToUserProfile", sender: view)

            print(view.annotation?.title) // annotation's title

            print(view.annotation?.subtitle) // annotation's subttitle


            //Perform a segue here to navigate to another viewcontroller
            // On tapping the disclosure button you will get here
        }
    }


    // Here we add disclosure button inside annotation window
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        print("viewForannotation")
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if pinView == nil {
            //println("Pinview was nil")
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        }

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign in it

        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button


        return pinView
    }
```

I'd like for the segue to happen when the annotation is clicked or double clicked, and then perform a segue to that new view controller while sending the specific username info as well. I'm pretty sure I'll be able to send the user info but I just need to figure out how to make the segue happen. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

**UPDATE** The problem may be that my CalloutAccessory isn't displaying. Check out this screenshot from when I click the pin in my app:

[MapView Annotation Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiSP7.png)

Comment: Have you created the segue in storyboard from your current VC to new one. Also is the identifier correct?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Yup that's all in order

Comment: Are you getting call inside map view Delegate ?? Have you set delegate of map view ?

Comment: @Anuraj yes I have set map view delegate

Comment: @FinnWolff Are you getting call inside delegate method?

Comment: Yes. The problem may be that my annotation callOutView isn't displaying. Check the image I posted in my update above

Comment: Since all I can see is the title and subtitle. I also have a tableview behind my MapView but that shouldn't affect this since it isn't viewable unless my search button is clicked